# Why do PageSpeedInsight results vary dramatically from one moment to the next

Tags: pagespeed-insights

If I press the Analyse button on the PageSpeedInsights page to analyse the same webpage over and over again, I get dramatically different results each time I run the test - varying from 9 to 45 (for the mobile test) for tests that are run only a few seconds apart, analysing the same webpage. Why do the results vary so wildly?

Comment: [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/variability) details all the possible causes of speed variability. Often it is caused by a poor performing server or race conditions within your code. Without some more information that is about the best we can offer in terms of an explanation I am afraid.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamRitchie. The website in question is [here]: https://jackieradophotography.com/. There is no handcoding on the site - it was all designed using the Cornerstone and 
Slider Revolution plugins for Wordpress by a web designer. It's hosted by HostPapa. I don't know what other Information I can provide or how to get it?

Comment: Is there any way of troubleshooting this and getting to the bottom of the cause?

Comment: one thing you can do is compare the items under "opportunities" and "diagnostics" and see what changes run to run. I noticed that "reduce initial server response time" came up twice out of 5 runs (pointing to poor hosting / overloaded server) and "defer offscreen images" came up once but not other times pointing to times when the images are served faster than others. Your "Time to First byte" is 2 seconds so that suggests either the page is building on the fly (so cache it), a DNS issue or hosting once again.

Comment: Hi @Graham. The page is already cached. It's very dissappointing that the hosting server is apparently to blame - we migrated the site to HostPapa very recently because they come at or near the top of all the lists of comaparative reviews that you get if you google for "best uk wordpress hosting company". Given that these comparative reviews are apparantly completely unreliable, is there any way to find out whether a hosting company's servers are fast or not without migrating to them first and then finding out the hard what that they're slow?

Comment: Also, how did you create your link in your first reply to me? None of the methods given [here] https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links seem to achieve that effect.

Comment: Hi Dave to do a link you do square brackets `[]` around the link text then parenthesis around the link destination `()`, they must not have any spaces between them. `[link text](https://google.com)` for example. I personally use [krystal hosting](https://krystal.co.uk) for clients as they are reliable and fast, but I am in the UK.

Comment: Hi @Graham 

I'm in the UK too. I went to Krystal's [contact page](https://krystal.uk/contact) and clicked on the "Chat with our team" button but nothing happened. I can see that their phone lines are only open on weekdays but is it normal for their chat not to work at weekends?

I'm confused about the difference between their "Web hosting" plan for £4.99 which says it's Wordpress optimised, and their "Wordpress hosting" plan for £14.99.

I've also been looking at [Guru](https://www.guru.co.uk/application-hosting/wordpress-hosting#ultimate)  - do you know anything about them?

Comment: I dont know any other hosting anymore as I have been with krystal about 4 years with no issues. They run a ticketing system out of hours, normal response time is about 4 hours but you can set things as urgent (as long as you don't abuse it otherwise they will disable it for a while for you). £4.99 is single cPanel, £14.99 is a reseller account, useful for multiple websites and you get WHM to manage everything. VPS starts at about £100 fully managed (i spend about £180) as I am not a good sys admin and they have installed a lot of things for me for that price that I wouldn't expect.

Comment: My VPS handles about 100,000 page views total no issue. My reseller package (as I still have one for "crappy sites") handles about 20,000 page views and I have only ever had one problem where another site (as it is shared hosting) was using all the resources, they just migrated my server for me, no fuss and no issues since.

Comment: Thanks @Graham. I can't open a ticket as I'm not a customer of theirs. Do you know if there's any size limit on the automated backups apart from the website site limit? I.e. I see the size limit for one's website (and presumably email) is 10GB for the basic plan - but is the automated backup size limit also 10GB? And does the basic plan include email? And if so is the 10GB size limit for one's website plus one's emails combined?

Also, does the basic plan use a cloud server?

By the way, their prices have gone up while we've been having this discussion!!

Comment: I do not know I am afraid, to be fair if you are putting more than 10GB of data up you will probably not want off the shelf hosting.